# PHP - String to (multi) Array - and loop

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry, I didn't know how to solve that question, actually I couldn't find the right words to search for a solution as well :)

I have a string as below

```
picture1.jpg, name1, role1; picture2.jpg, name2, role2; picture3.jpg, name2, role2;
```

Is there way that I can loop it to get something like that

```
loop start
<img src='$image' />$name as $role
loop ends
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    $str = 'picture1.jpg, name1, role1; picture2.jpg, name2, role2; picture3.jpg, name2, role2;';
    $items = explode(';', $str);
    foreach ($items as $row) {
        $arr = explode(',', $row);
        echo sprintf('<img src="%s"/> %s as %s', trim($arr[0]),trim($arr[1]),trim($arr[2]));
    }
```

Comment: Works beautifully :) But for some reason, it returns a 7th empty row. I added a $count++ and brake the output right at 6th one (each string has 6 rows). Thanks Bartek

Comment: :) Found the reason, it was because of last line break "\n";

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution will be:

```
function output($input) {

  $output = '';

  $segments = explode(';', $input);

  if (count($segments))
  {
    foreach ($segments as $segment)
    {
      $values = explode(',', $segment);

      if (count($values) === 3)
      {
        $values = array_map(function($value) {
          return trim($value);
        }, $values);

        $output .= '<img src="'.$values[0].'">';
        $output .= ' '.$values[1];
        $output .= ' as '.$values[2];
      }
    }
  }

  return $output;
}

$input = "picture1.jpg, name1, role1; picture2.jpg, name2, role2; picture3.jpg, name2, role2;";

echo output($input);
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, i got a syntax error issue thou, something to do with this line.

        $values = array_map(function($value) {
          return trim($value);
        }, $values);

Comment: the array_map function is available since (PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5), which is your version?
The function is tested and works XD!

Comment: Strange, the PHP version is 5.2.42. 
The error message i do get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ') ....."

Comment: The problem is Anonymous function which not available for PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this short version:

```
$str = 'picture1.jpg, name1, role1; picture2.jpg, name2, role2; picture3.jpg, name2, role2;';

function picture_name_role ($val) {
    $pnr = array_filter(explode(',', $val));
    list($picture, $name, $role) = $pnr;
    return '<img src="' . trim($picture) . '"/>' . trim($name) . ' as ' . trim($role);
}

$f = array_map('picture_name_role', array_filter(explode(';', $str)));

var_dump($f);
```